# Can't understand this code

Tags: javascript

I can't understand this code.
please help me

```
function HelloFunc(func){
    this.greeting = "hello";
}

HelloFunc.prototype.call = function(func){
    func? func(this.greeting) : this.func(this.greeting);
}

var userFunc = function(greeting){
     console.log(greeting);
}

var objHello = new HelloFunc();
objHello.func = userFunc;
objHello.call();
```

func? func(this.greeting) : this.fun(this.greeting);

what's that mean?

also, I can't understand that code on the whole
please explane that code

Comment: EEEck.  Code should not attempt to override/replace the `fn.call()`.  Make your own function name that doesn't conflict with built-in names.

Comment: I can't understand it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the ternary ?:-operator and can be rewritten as:

```
if (func) {
    func(this.greeting);
} else {
    this.func(this.greeting);
}
```

Only difference is, that the original expression has a value, but in the code snippet above it isn't used anyway.

Comment: how does 'func' work in that code?

Comment: `func` seems to be an optional parameter, which holds a function (which is a first-order value in javascript) when set. `if (func)` checks, if it was passed by the caller or not. In the first case, this function is called, in the latter case some default function is.